# Set readonly field only first line (Kendo UI)

Tags: kendo-ui

I'd like to set readonly field, but **only first** line on the grid. How can I do this?

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the edit function like

```
edit: function(e) {

      //add your custom logic here as if condition 
      //as for this example it just disable the one with id 1
      //or maybe ada a new attribute like isEditable = boolean upon datasource.parse then check it
      if (e.model.id == 1) {
         //revert edited cell back to `read` mode
         this.closeCell();
      }
}
```

Well this is not exactly prevent opening, its just immediately close it after it opened i think. but it is viable option since i cant even see the changes. Working example [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/oMEqU) and this actually sugested in the [kendo forum here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/when-editing-a-grid-how-do-i-disable-specific-fields-by-row)